# how to get parent objects keys in nested object in jq?

Tags: json, path, nested, key, jq

I have JSON with nested objects

```
{
 "schema1": {
    "table1": {
        "status": 0
    },
    "table2": {
        "status": 1
    }
 },
 "schema2": {
    "table1": {
        "status": 0
    },
    "table2": {
        "status": 1
    }
 }
}
```

I need in list of schema.table filtered by status==1.
My first approach is

```
.[]|.[]|(select(.status==1))|"table.schema  \(.status)"
```

How to replace table.schema with appropriated keys of parent objects?

[Here is jq play with example](https://jqplay.org/s/2sNgnu-__L)

The expected result is:

```
[ "schema1.table2", "schema2.table2" ]
```

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: expected result is 
     ```[
          "schema1.table2",
          "schema2.table2"
     ]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input document were so large that it would not fit comfortably in memory, then a solution using jq's streaming parser would be appropriate.

To this end, consider program.jq as follows:

```
select(length==2 and .[-1] == 1 and .[0][-1] == "status")
| .[0][:-1]
| join(".")
```

(Here `[:-1]` is a compact way of writing `[0:-1]`, which in effect takes all but the last items in an array.)

The invocation: `jq --stream -f program.jq input.json`

would produce the stream:

```
"schema1.table2"
"schema2.table2"
```

If an array of values is required, you could pipe this stream into `jq -s .`

Notice also that program.jq as above actually solves the generic problem in which the nesting can be arbitrarily deep.

Comment: for json ~ 70mb this approach takes ~ 7sec

Comment: For a scaleable solution to the most generic problem (variable-depth), this may be about as good as jq can offer.

Answer (score 4):

I've choose such solution

```
path(.[]|.[]|select(.status==1))|join(".")
```

Comment: This is good, but doesn't meet the stated requirement about producing an array. FYI, you can abbreviate `.[]|.[]` to `.[][]`. Could you please post your 70MB timing for this approach?

Comment: It takes ~ 3sec

Answer (score 1):

The following uses `to_entries` (twice) to produce the array as requested:

```
[to_entries[]
 |  .key as $k
 | .value | to_entries | map(select(.value.status == 1))[]
 | [$k, .key]
 | join(".") ]
```

Comment: this is the fastest approach.
For json file ~ 70mb it takes ~3sec

Comment: but what if I have 6 levels of nested objects?
Maybe you have more compact and fast solution for many levels?

Comment: I’d suggest upvoting/accepting, as appropriate, the answers to the question as originally posed, and then asking a new question more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq -r '. as $o | paths 
       | select(length == 3) 
       | select($o[.[0]][.[1]][.[2]] == 1) 
       | .[0] +"."+ .[1]' file.json
```

The output:

```
schema1.table2
schema2.table2
```

Comment: for json size ~ 70mb it takes 12sec
and this approach do not use "status" directly

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could use `paths(scalars)` (formerly `leaf_paths`) to obtain paths to all the scalar values. With these paths, you could use `getpath/1` to get the value and output the desired strings.

```
paths(scalars) as $p
  | select($p[-1] == "status" and getpath($p) == 1)
  | "\([$p[1,0]] | join(".")) \(getpath($p))"
```

---

If you want to get fancy, you can also use streams to get paths and values in one go.

```
tostream as [$p,$v]
  | select($p[-1] == "status" and $v == 1)
  | "\([$p[1,0]] | join(".")) \($v)"
```

---

But considering your comment, if you just need the paths, it could all be boiled down to simply:

```
[tostream as [$p,$v]
  | select($p[-1] == "status" and $v == 1)
  | $p[:2] | join(".")
]
```

Comment: for json size ~ 70mb first approach takes ~70sec, second ~ 22sec

Comment: @JeffMercado - The second call to `getpath($p)` is contrary to the requirements and probably accounts for much of the reported slowness. @АлександрКоролёв - Could you perhaps post the timing for the first solution after removing the aforementioned call to getpath($p) so readers can make relevant comparisons?  Also, could you post a link to your test data?

Comment: For the record, Jeff's solution can easily be made more efficient and completely generic as follows: paths(scalars) as $p
  | select($p[-1] == "status" and getpath($p) == 1)
  | $p[:-1] | join(".")

Comment: solution 
       `paths(scalars) as $p | select($p[-1] == "status" and getpath($p) == 1)  |"\([$p[1,0]] | join(".")) \(getpath($p))"` takes 22sec on 70мб json

Comment: solution 
       `paths(scalars) as $p | select($p[-1] == "status" and getpath($p) == 1)  |"\([$p[1,0]] | join(".")) \(getpath($p))"` takes 22sec on 70мб json


solution `paths(scalars) as $p | select($p[-1] == "status" and getpath($p) == 1) | $p[:-1] | join(".")` takes the same 3sec

sorry, I can't put here my 70mb json...